# How to speed up my "friends list" MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a friend list from my database and my query is working but takes lot of time to load the results (sometimes about 10 seconds).

Here it is :

```
SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email, UI.country, UI.birthday, P.thumb_url
FROM user U, relation F, user_info UI, photo P 
WHERE
CASE
WHEN F.leader = 'USER_ID'
THEN F.subscriber = U.id
WHEN F.subscriber= 'USER_ID'
THEN F.leader= U.id
END
AND
U.id = UI.user_id
AND
UI.main_photo = P.id
AND
F.status='1';
```

My "relation" table is as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `leader` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscriber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `seen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

So my question is : do you have some good suggestions in order to improve my query ?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be using filters where you should be using table joins.

Comment: The join keyword has been around for 25 years. It's best practice to use it.

Comment: I'm going to assume that `USER_ID` is a placeholder of the ID of the user you're building the list for.  Also your schema is invalid, time has no DEFAULT.

Comment: WHERE CASE ... END always evaluates as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

So I have found a good solution using the JOIN syntax instead of the case. I post it here since it could help some of you.

```
SELECT username, email, ui.gender, ui.country, ui.birthday, p.thumb_url
FROM relation
RIGHT JOIN user ON
(user.`id` = relation.`leader`
OR
user.`id` = relation.`subscriber`)
AND
user.`id` != '?'
AND
relation.`status` = '1'
JOIN user_info ui, photo p
WHERE
(relation.`leader` = '?'
OR
relation.`subscriber` = '?')
AND user.`id` = ui.`user_id`
AND ui.`main_photo` = p.`id`;
```

This query takes only around 100ms to load the results whereas it was around 5 seconds for the first one I posted...

Comment: Yes, joining on relation makes more sense for building a friend list.  There's still ways to improve this query, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: PS  Why did you decide on a RIGHT JOIN?

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, if you're using a CASE (or any other if/then logic) in SQL you're probably doing it wrong.  SQL is a declarative language, which means you ask it questions.  If you're telling it how to answer the question, it'll probably end badly (or slowly).  The key is to put the constraining user ID in the WHERE clause and keep it out of the join.  That changes it from telling the database how to do its job, to asking the database.  The database will take care of the rest.

Using JOIN syntax makes it clearer what's a join and what's a constraint.  [SQL joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) are the thing to use when you want rows from multiple tables stitched together.  Databases know how to optimize them.

The second bit is to [use EXPLAIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) to tell you how MySQL is executing the query, where it's slow.  This usually indicates where you need indexes or what part of the query needs to be rewritten.

I'm going to assume that `Relationship.leader` and `Relationship.subscriber` are both foreign keys on `User.id` and describe who is following that user and who they are following, and you want to show every user related to a given `USER_ID`.  There should be no need for the CASE, you can just check if either matches (check me on that one).

```
SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email, UI.country, UI.birthday, P.thumb_url
FROM user U
JOIN user_info UI
  ON U.id = UI.user_id
JOIN photo P
  ON UI.main_photo = P.id
JOIN relation F
  ON F.leader = U.id OR F.subscriber = U.id
WHERE F.status='1'
  AND U.id = ?
```

**UPDATE**: Understanding now that it's supposed to be a list of friends of the user, change `U.id = ?` to check that user is in the relationship instead.

```
SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email, UI.country, UI.birthday, P.thumb_url
FROM user U
JOIN user_info UI
  ON U.id = UI.user_id
JOIN photo P
  ON UI.main_photo = P.id
JOIN relation F
  ON F.leader = U.id OR F.subscriber = U.id
WHERE F.status='1'
  AND F.leader = ? OR F.subscriber = ?
```

We want a list of relationships, but we're using Users as the main table.  That's a bit awkward.  [@fraxool's query which is FROM relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537041/14660) makes more sense, but it could use some clean up about what constraint goes where.  JOIN ON is *only* about meshing tables.  WHERE is for constraining what gets returned overall.  Applying these principles to @fraxool's new query, we get...

```
SELECT username, email, ui.gender, ui.country, ui.birthday, p.thumb_url
FROM relation R
JOIN user U
  ON U.id = R.leader OR U.id = R.subscriber
JOIN user_info UI
  ON U.id = UI.user_id
JOIN photo P
  ON UI.main_photo = P.id
WHERE R.status = 1
  AND (R.leader = ? OR R.subscriber = ?)
```

The additional constraint of `U.id != ?` is unnecessary unless you can be your own friend.  That's something which should be handled in column constraints on relation.leader and relation.subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! In fact, I also tried with the JOIN syntax, but it gave me wrong results... But I think that my query was not correct.

With your query, I have a list of results with the right number of rows... But it returns the infos of the current user (where U.id = ?) on each row and I want the informations of the friends of this user. I am actually working on your query but if you have a suggestion, I'll take it too!

Thanks again!

Comment: @fraxool I think changing `U.id = ?` to `F.leader = ? OR F.subscriber = ?` would do it.